# Tornado IOLoop Exception in callback None in Celery worker

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, tornado

I am using `tornado.ioloop` inside `celery` worker because I need to use mongodb.

```
class WorkerBase():
    @gen.engine
    def foo(self,args,callback)
        bar = ['Python','Celery','Javascript','HTML']

        # ... process something ....

        callback(bar)

    @gen.engine
    def RunMyTask(self,args):

        result = yield gen.Task(self.foo,args=args)
        # Stop IOLoop instance
        IOLoop.instance().stop()


@task(name="MyWorker",base=WorkerBase)
def CeleryWorker(args):
    # This works because i'm adding base as WorkerBase
    CeleryWorker.RunMyTask(args)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
    return True
```

When I am invoking a task it gives an error saying:

```
[2014-10-02 12:12:11,561: ERROR/Worker-4] Exception in callback None
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/www/myapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 832, in start
fd_obj, handler_func = self._handlers[fd]
KeyError: 16
```

or

```
[2014-10-02 12:12:11,561: ERROR/Worker-4] Exception in callback None
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/www/myapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 832, in start
fd_obj, handler_func = self._handlers[fd]
KeyError: 14
```

These errors are not consistent. Is there any raise condition?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a threading problem. I'm not familiar with celery's threading model but it looks like it's starting multiple copies of CeleryWorker, each of which is trying to run the same singleton IOLoop.instance(). Each worker thread needs its own IOLoop if you're going to run it like this - look at what the synchronous [tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/6f3f2561cb5fb25785358ba604ecd51219e6efda/tornado/httpclient.py#L54) does to create and run a temporary IOLoop

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It turns out that celery is not working well with IOLoop because the way it interacts with the method. Our primary reason was to make it work with Motor. So we decided to stop using it instead using PyMongo driver.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your worker task just return and being treated as finished before ioloop stops, so gen.engine's callback cannot find the original stack_context I guess.

> ```
> @task(name="MyWorker",base=WorkerBase)
> def CeleryWorker(args):
>     # This works because i'm adding base as WorkerBase
>     CeleryWorker.RunMyTask(args)
>     IOLoop.instance().start()
>     return True
> ```

I have some suggestion for you

1) remove return

```
@task(name="MyWorker",base=WorkerBase)
def CeleryWorker(args):
    # This works because i'm adding base as WorkerBase
    CeleryWorker.RunMyTask(args)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

2) use run_sync

```
import functools

@task(name="MyWorker",base=WorkerBase)
def CeleryWorker(args):
    # This works because i'm adding base as WorkerBase
    func = functools.partial(CeleryWorker.RunMyTask, args)
    IOLoop.instance().run_sync(func)
```

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that celery is not working well with IOLoop because the way it interacts with the method. 
 Our primary reason was to make it work with Motor(MongoDB driver for tornado). So we decided to stop using it instead using PyMongo driver.

Comment: understood, but you will lose the power of non-blocking... ;-)